# How to delete all the elements from the combo box in nsis

Tags: combobox, nsis

I want to delete all the elements from the combo box on click of the button in the nsis installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nsDialogs does not have helper macros for every feature implemented by the Windows controls so sometimes you have to consult [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx) to find information about which message to send yourself.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
Page Custom MyPageCreate
Page InstFiles

Var MyComboHandle

Function ResetCombo
Pop $0
SendMessage $MyComboHandle ${CB_RESETCONTENT} 0 0
FunctionEnd

Function DeleteItemsButNotText
Pop $0
${NSD_GetText} $MyComboHandle $0
SendMessage $MyComboHandle ${CB_RESETCONTENT} 0 0
${NSD_SetText} $MyComboHandle $0
FunctionEnd
Function DeleteItemsButNotText_AlternateVersion
Pop $0
loop:
    SendMessage $MyComboHandle ${CB_DELETESTRING} 0 0 $0 ; This will also clear the text if it matches the item
    IntCmp $0 ${CB_ERR} "" loop loop
FunctionEnd

Function AddItems
Pop $0
${NSD_CB_AddString} $MyComboHandle "Foo"
${NSD_CB_AddString} $MyComboHandle "Bar"
SendMessage $MyComboHandle ${CB_SETCURSEL} 0 ""
FunctionEnd


Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCombobox} 0 30u 100% 200u ""
Pop $MyComboHandle
Push ""
Call AddItems

${NSD_CreateButton} 0 50u 33% 12u "Reset"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 ResetCombo

${NSD_CreateButton} 33% 50u 33% 12u "Delete all items"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 DeleteItemsButNotText

${NSD_CreateButton} 66% 50u 33% 12u "Add items"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 AddItems

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```